# How to save non required properties to datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a basic class:

```
class Post (db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    text = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True).

new_record = Post(title = "TESSSST", text = "TESSST") 
new_record.put() #works!
```

And it is works fine - the instances are created and the data is written. But as soon as I remove "required=true" property is no longer stored in the datastore:

```
class Post (db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    text = db.TextProperty  
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

new_record = Post(title = "TESSSST")
new_record.text = "Burn conctructor!"
new_record.put() # text property won't be saved
```

I don't know if it be helpful but when I checking properties via `print new_record.__dict__` all values that was assigned by constructor has '_' prefix (like '_title') and other don't have (just 'text').

So the question is "Is it possible to save to datastore non required (and not initialised by constructor) properies?"  I couldn't find answer in gae docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you haven't just removed `required=True`, you've removed the brackets `()` which instantiate the field. It should be

```
text = db.TextProperty()
```

Comment: and you can add a default value so rather than None returned you could set default=''